# Unable to install/fix caffeinate (caffeine)

Tags: linux, apt

I'm unable to run the caffeinate command

```
caffeinate
```

> The program 'caffeinate' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>       sudo apt install caffeine

but when I install it (type the suggested command):

```
sudo apt install caffeine
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>       Building dependency tree
>       Reading state information... Done
>       caffeine is already the newest version (2.8.3-3build1).
>       0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 67 not to upgrade.

it seems to be installed already, and `caffeinate` gives the same error.

I don't have the following file: /usr/bin/caffeinate
I deleted it and planned to reinstall since it was not recognising commands. e.g. `-t` in `caffeinate -t 18000` was not recognised. But I don't know how to reinstall it.

I'm using GNOME Shell 3.18.5.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked for me. In case you broke your installation, you can try

```
sudo apt purge caffeine
sudo apt install caffeine
```

(this have helped me with other packages).

Otherwise, I'd suggest you ask on the `https://unix.stackexchange.com/` forum as more appropriate.